# How to handle missing coordinates for a page in the Wikipedia Python API

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I try to display page coordinates. However, some pages do not have coordinates and the API then acts funny.

For:

```
from wikipedia import wikipedia, DisambiguationError

   try:
        page = wikipedia.page("West Side Highway")
    except DisambiguationError as exception:
        page = wikipedia.page(exception.options[0], auto_suggest=False)
```

when I try to validate if there are some coordinates:

```
    if page.coordinates is None:
        print("no coordinates")
```

I keep getting the `KeyError` from the `wikipedia` lib:

```
if page.coordinates is None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mav/.pyenv/versions/stories_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 570, in coordinates
    coordinates = request['query']['pages'][self.pageid]['coordinates']
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'coordinates'
```

How can I catch this lack of `coordinates` for a page to handle it?

Comment: What is `the_page` ? Please provide minimum reproducible example

Comment: `try:`/`coordinates = page.coordinates`/`except KeyError`/`print(...)`? You already have one `try`-`catch` block, haven't you?

Comment: @InSync Yes thank you. You are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be from the library itself.
According to this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/pull/157), the library doesn't do anything to prevent the KeyError. It's up to you to use try/except to guard against the error. For example:

```
from wikipedia import wikipedia, DisambiguationError

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        page = wikipedia.page("West Side Highway") 
        print(page.coordinates)
    except KeyError:
        print("No coordinates")
    except DisambiguationError as exception:
        page = wikipedia.page(exception.options[0], auto_suggest=False)
```